# C# reader.HasRows returns false all the time, even if I still have rows in the table

Tags: c#

```
password = md5Crypt(password);
User u = null;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" + username + "' AND password='" + password + "'";
try
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Read();
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Read());


   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
        u = new User(reader["username"].ToString(), reader["password"].ToString(), reader["name"].ToString(), reader["role"].ToString());

   }
   else
   {
        u = null;
   }
   conn.Close();

}
catch (MySqlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    conn.Close();
    return null;
}
return u;
```

Comment: @Tim But that takes the fun away. At least at the moment I can try to login as username `' or 1 = 1; -- ` and maybe get an admin account.

Comment: @John: Deleted comment because added as answer. You're right, others have fun now:)

Answer (score 4):

**Never** use string concatenatation to build your sql query. Instead use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection and other issues. That's the real issue.

But to fix your bug, you are calling `MySqlDataReader.Read` twice in a row. This will advance the reader to the next record.  Instead do it only once:

```
if(reader.Read())
{
    u = new User(reader["username"].ToString(), reader["password"].ToString(), reader["name"].ToString(), reader["role"].ToString());
}
else
{
   u = null;
}
if(reader.Read())
{
    // bug detected, two user with same name and password, log this/throw an exception
}
```

Also use the `using` statemennt (or try-catch-finally) for the connection to ensure that it gets disposed/closed everytime, even in case of an error.